# as3 moving image from one mc to another

Tags: actionscript-3

With the code below I created some imgMcA and some imgMcB then I loaded images into imgMcA ones. ImgMcBs have no image at that moment. So if one of imgMcA is clicked the image should be transferred to one of the empty imgMcBs (may be randomly) and if imgmcB is clicked later  the image should move  back to its imgMcA back. I could not find out how  I can accomplish this.

Thanks in advance

```
 function imageList(mcname, img, index){

    var imgMcA:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
    imgMcA.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    imgMcA.graphics.drawRect(0,0,imgWidth,imgHeight);
    imgMcA.graphics.endFill();
    imgMcA.name=lemma;
    imgMcA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveImage);


    var imgMcB:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
    imgMcB.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    imgMcB.graphics.drawRect(0,0,imgWidth,imgHeight);
    imgMcB.graphics.endFill();
    imgMcB.name=index;
    addChild(imgMcB);


    var imgLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(img));
    imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, changeProperties);
    imgLoader.mouseEnabled=false;
    imgMcA.addChild(imgLoader);

  }

  function moveImage(evnt:MouseEvent){

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could linked mcA & mcB by adding them to the same parent.

```
function createBlock():void
{
   var imgLoader:Loader = new Loader();
   //add the loading code here...

   var mcA:Sprite = new Sprite();
   var mcB:Sprite = new Sprite();
   // add Click event listeners for both Mcs here...

   var parent:Sprite = new Sprite();

   //add Children
   parent.addChild(mcA);
   parent.addChild(mcB);
   addChild(parent);
}

function mouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent)
{
    var dispatcher:Sprite = event.currentTarget as Sprite;

    //if you added a Loader to it
    if( dispatcher.numChildren > 0)
    {
        //retrieve the image
        var img:Loader = dispatcher.getChildAt(0);

        //identify the parent
        var parent:Sprite = dispatcher.parent;

        var index:int = parent.getChildIndex(dispatcher);

        //identify the receiving MC
        //of course this only works with two children!!!
        if(index > 0)
            var receiver:Sprite = parent.getChildAt(0) as Sprite;
        else
            receiver = parent.getChildAt(1) as Sprite;

        //add the image to the other MC 
        receiver.addChild(img); 

    }
}
```

The rest is not too complicated to achieve. You will need to use a Boolean and add a TextField. If the TextField contains text, set the Boolean to true.

It may be worth looking at Classes or you could use an Object as a container for the MovieClips, the TextField and the Boolean, although a Class will give you more flexibility...

With a Class, you wouldn't have to iterate in order to find what does what. Your Click listener would look something like this:

```
private function mouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent)
{
   receiver.addChild( image );
   if( hasText)
    imageReturn(); 
}
```

Comment: hi Patrick, Thank you I got the logic. There is something I noticed. The number of images can be more than one. This code produces only one mc of A and B.  I think this is because both McA and B  have been defined outside imageList function.  When I defined them inside, it produces  mcs for every image. But this time imgMcA and B vars in changeProperties remain undefined .

Comment: what I have in my mind is: Say, I have 5 images or more. so first I create McAs for each of these images; then I create empty McBs as many as images. At the end I have one row of McAs with images loaded inside and McBs without images. If a user clicks one of McAs, the image inside moves to one of the emtpty McB or vice versa and so on

Comment: Check edited answer. Of course I haven't put all the details but the main logic should work

Comment: Hi Patrick, sorry to keep you busy. let me tell what I am trying to accomplish. I read the data from xml which is a list of  words (lemma) and their images. Now imagine a row 0f five empty squares and a row of five images . Behind every image there will also be a word (which user do not see). When they click any one of the 5 images, clicked image will move to one of the empty square and the word behind will be seen. If images is clicked while in empty square they go back to their previous place. So there wil possibly more than two children  in the first row initiated with images and words.

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thank you the logic you suggest works. Thanks again